# Profile.Name accesability linked to 'View setup and configuration' System Permission

Tags: apex, fflib

Apparently, ***getDescribe()*** is returning ***isAccessible=false*** for the field **Profile.Name** (User object) if the System Permission 'View setup and configuration' is disabled.

> tokenDescribeSchema.DescribeFieldResult[getByteLength=18;getCalculatedFormula=null;getCompoundFieldName=null;getController=null;getDataTranslationEnabled=null;getDefaultValue=null;getDefaultValueFormula=null;getDigits=0;getFilteredLookupInfo=null;getInlineHelpText=null;getLabel=Id. de perfil;getLength=18;getLocalName=ProfileId;getMask=null;getMaskType=null;getName=ProfileId;getPrecision=0;getReferenceTargetField=null;getRelationshipName=Profile;getRelationshipOrder=null;getScale=0;getSoapType=ID;getSobjectField=ProfileId;getSObjectType=User;getType=REFERENCE;**isAccessible=false**;isAggregatable=true;isAiPredictionField=false;isAutoNumber=false;isCalculated=false;isCascadeDelete=false;isCaseSensitive=false;isCreateable=false;isCustom=false;isDefaultedOnCreate=false;isDependentPicklist=false;isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;isDisplayLocationInDecimal=false;isEncrypted=false;isExternalId=false;isFilterable=true;isFormulaTreatNullNumberAsZero=false;isGroupable=true;isHighScaleNumber=false;isHtmlFormatted=false;isIdLookup=false;isNameField=false;isNamePointing=false;isNillable=false;isPermissionable=false;isQueryByDistance=false;isRestrictedDelete=false;isSearchPrefilterable=true;isSortable=true;isUnique=false;isUpdateable=false;isWriteRequiresMasterRead=false;]

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this makes sense. A user that doesn't have View Setup and Configuration cannot view the UserRole or Profile objects, and so any lookup fields that reference these objects are also inaccessible.